# Подскажите путь к хедеру сайта на вордпресе, тема woordmart

Tags: php, wordpress

Я открыла обычно, где всегда находила. wp-content\themes(тема)woodmart. Но там нет ни одного файла, где можно поменять ссылку изображения. Изображение - имеется ввиду логотип. Он был в формате свг, но изображения пропали, теперь хочу поставить пнг. Так же нужно, что бы это было на всех страницах. Но в каталоге я не вижу папок с страницами. На скрине содержимое файла хейдер в папке woodmart.[image: скрин хейдер]

Comment: Как правило, логотип в подобных темах Вы можете поменять в админ панели, незачем для этого лезть в header.

Comment: Так не могу найти. Поэтому полезла в каталог. Где в админ панели это редактируется? В виджетах нет, в меню - нет, в настройке темы - нет.

Comment: Если что, на будущее, у таких тем как правило есть [документация](https://xtemos.com/documentation/woodmart/) где можно прочесть как настроить тему, работать с тем же header builder и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

Поменяла в админке в header builder.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).